# why docker container exits with code 0?

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, botkit

I am currently trying to create a Messenger Bot with Botkit framework !

Since I work on different computers I want to use docker to prevent any local configurations problems.

Unfortunately, I am new to botkit AND docker.

### file structure

```
bot
├── README.md
├── docker
│   ├── botkit
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── node
│       └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── node_modules
└── package.json

4 directories, 5 files
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
    node:
        build: ./docker/node
        volumes_from:
            - "app"
    botkit:
        build: ./docker/botkit
        links:
            - "node"
        volumes_from:
            - "app"
    app:
        image: "node:8"
        working_dir: /home/nook_bot
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=production
        volumes:
            - .:/home/nook_bot
            - /home/nook_bot/node_modules
        command: "npm init --yes && npm start"
```

### docker/botkit/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
RUN npm install botkit
```

### docker/node/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8
EXPOSE 8888
```

### Steps to reproduce the error

When I run

```
docker-compose build
```

I've got

```
app uses an image, skipping
Building node
Step 1/2 : FROM node:8
8: Pulling from library/node
f2b6b4884fc8: Pull complete
4fb899b4df21: Pull complete
74eaa8be7221: Pull complete
2d6e98fe4040: Pull complete
452c06dec5fa: Pull complete
7b3c215894de: Pull complete
094529398b79: Pull complete
449fe646e95b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:26e4c77f9f797c3993780943239fa79419f011dd93ae4e0097089e2145aeaa24
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:8
 ---> 4635bc7d130c
Step 2/2 : EXPOSE 8888
 ---> Running in 3a5be5fca913
Removing intermediate container 3a5be5fca913
 ---> 87cf54fd2907
Successfully built 87cf54fd2907
Successfully tagged nook_bot_node:latest
Building botkit
Step 1/2 : FROM node:8
 ---> 4635bc7d130c
Step 2/2 : RUN npm install botkit
 ---> Running in d57d1ac5e112
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data
npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.

+ botkit@0.6.13
added 349 packages in 48.021s
Removing intermediate container d57d1ac5e112
 ---> 6530cdad7dfe
Successfully built 6530cdad7dfe
Successfully tagged nook_bot_botkit:latest
```

Then I do

```
docker-compose up
```

I get

```
Creating nook_bot_app_1 ... done
Creating nook_bot_node_1 ... done
Creating nook_bot_botkit_1 ... done
Attaching to nook_bot_app_1, nook_bot_node_1, nook_bot_botkit_1
app_1     | Wrote to /home/nook_bot/package.json:
app_1     |
app_1     | {
app_1     |   "name": "nook_bot",
app_1     |   "version": "1.0.0",
app_1     |   "description": "",
app_1     |   "main": "index.js",
app_1     |   "dependencies": {},
app_1     |   "devDependencies": {},
app_1     |   "scripts": {
app_1     |     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
app_1     |   },
app_1     |   "repository": {
app_1     |     "type": "git",
app_1     |     "url": "git+https://github.com/Geoffrey42/nook_bot.git"
app_1     |   },
app_1     |   "keywords": [],
app_1     |   "author": "",
app_1     |   "license": "ISC",
app_1     |   "bugs": {
app_1     |     "url": "https://github.com/Geoffrey42/nook_bot/issues"
app_1     |   },
app_1     |   "homepage": "https://github.com/Geoffrey42/nook_bot#readme"
app_1     | }
app_1     |
app_1     |
nook_bot_node_1 exited with code 0
nook_bot_app_1 exited with code 0
nook_bot_botkit_1 exited with code 0
```

If I ran

```
docker exec -ti nook_bot_app_1 bash
```

I get

```
Error response from daemon: Container a4c9724bc954c6bab19a5953c2fea315b95caf64f26c8ca0b036ca3f037fd398 is not running
```

### logs

I ran

```
docker logs nook_bot_app_1
```

I get

```
Wrote to /home/nook_bot/package.json:

{
  "name": "nook_bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Geoffrey42/nook_bot.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Geoffrey42/nook_bot/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Geoffrey42/nook_bot#readme"
}
```

I don't understand how come docker doesn't find my package.json file since by running docker-compose build and up it does create the file. I suppose the exit code 0 issue come from here but I really don't understand why.
Maybe I lack some basic understanding on how docker actually works.

I searched for other questions about exit code 0 but none of the answers was helpful.

In the end I just want to run bash on my app container in order to start building my bot.

Thanks for any further help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that Docker, before building your image, needs to prepare a context in which it will build your files. You have your package.json, but you never really added it to your image context.

You should read about `COPY <src> <dest>` from Dockerfile docs.

> The COPY instruction will copy new files from `<src>` and add them to the  > container's filesystem at path `<dest>`

Answer (score 5):

Try `tty: true`:

> node:
>
> ```
> build: ./docker/node
>
> volumes_from:
>     - "app"
>     tty: true
> ```

This worked for me with PHP and MySQL container.